# Sending push notification to specific user using FCM on button click from the app.

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have just integrated FCM in my app.

Now, I have to know that is it possible to send a custom notification to specific user of the app and from the application and not from the firebase console ?

Comment: You can send it from the application; however this would require knowing the recipient's ID. So it would be a better idea to send a request to the server, and let the server send the push notification request to FCM servers.

Comment: Possible but *strongly* not advisable. In order to send a notification, you would need the Server Key, which is something that must be always kept safe and a secret, stored as much as possible only on the server side. Putting it in a client app exposes it to unauthorized users and risks for abuse.

Comment: So, instead of notifying another user of the same app, what else should be implemented instead of notification ?